# how can i input tasks in Genetic algorithm with three different orders?

Tags: genetic-algorithm

for example my initial input tasks set {1,2,3,4,5} then i want to create three different orders like Gene1=1,3,5,42 gene2=1,5,4,2,3 and gene3=5,2,3,4,1 these are three different orders of tasks i want to sort out all tasks randomly to produce three different orders the different orders of tasks correspond to different genetic code is there any example for this problem in java or any language

Answer (score 0):

You can shuffle the initial input tasks set

The following code presents random permutations of the genes 1,2,3,4

```
 List<Integer> all_genes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        all_genes.add(1);
        all_genes.add(2);
        all_genes.add(3);
        all_genes.add(4);


        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            List<Integer> temp_gene = new ArrayList<Integer>(all_genes);
            java.util.Collections.shuffle(all_genes);
            System.out.println(all_genes);
        }
```

Comment: yes but i need this output using genetic algorithm can you please use genetic algorithm?

Comment: This is how you would initialise a genetic algorithm.  Add p permutations to make a population of size p. You then need to apply selection, crossover and mutation to generate a new population. Selection can only be done when there is a fitness/objective function so that fitter solutions can be selected. I can add some simply functions with the assumption that I know what the fitness should be, if you’d like

Comment: could you please give me some example of this how can design genetic algorithm for this please it my request please sir thank you

Comment: I have now posted a full implementation of a simple permutation GA with simple assumptions. I hope this helps

Comment: Simper permutation genetic algorithm is presented here https://github.com/mayoayodele/Permutation-GA

Answer (score 0):

A simple permutation GA would follow the simple process of:

- Selection (select better solutions, this is why fitness i.e quality of a solution is needed)
- Crossover (get offspring solutions from parent solutions)
- Mutation (make a small change to the offspring to encourage variation in solutions)

While stopping criteria is not met.

If the quality of the permutation problem is estimated as `x*gene[x]` for all position x in the solution.

I defined two classes, the first one is the GA itself as shown below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class SimplePermuationGA {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int number_of_generations = 10;
        int problem_size = 4;
        int population_size = 30;
        float crossover_probability = 0.7f;
        float mutation_probability = 0.01f;
        GAOperators operators = new GAOperators(population_size, problem_size, crossover_probability, mutation_probability);

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> population = operators.getInitialSolutions();

        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_generations; i++) {
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> new_population = operators.performSelection(population);
            population = (ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>) new_population.clone();
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> best_solution = population.get(0);
        int best_fitness = operators.evaluationSolution(best_solution);
        for (int i = 0; i < population_size; i++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> solution = population.get(i);

            int fitness = operators.evaluationSolution(solution);

            if (best_fitness < fitness) {
                best_fitness = fitness;
                best_solution = (ArrayList<Integer>) solution.clone();

            }

        }
        System.out.println(best_solution);
        System.out.println(best_fitness);

    }

}
```

The second class contains all the genetic operators (i.e selection, crossover and mutation), it also contains the evaluation and initialisation functions for simplicity. See below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;



public class GAOperators {
    int problem_size;
    int population_size;
    float crossover_probability;
    float mutation_probability;
    Random r;

    public GAOperators(int population_size, int problem_size, float crossover_probability, float mutation_probability) {
        this.problem_size = problem_size;
        this.population_size = population_size;
        this.crossover_probability = crossover_probability;
        this.mutation_probability = mutation_probability;
        r = new Random();

    }


    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getInitialSolutions() {
        ArrayList<Integer> all_genes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < problem_size; i++) {
              all_genes.add(i);
        }

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> population = new ArrayList<>();


        for (int i = 0; i < population_size; i++) {
            List<Integer> temp_gene = new ArrayList<>(all_genes);
            java.util.Collections.shuffle(all_genes);
            population.add(all_genes);
        }
        return population;
    }


    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> performSelection(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> population)
    {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> new_population = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < population_size; i++) {
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> parents = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                ArrayList<Integer> parent_temp1 = population.get(r.nextInt(population_size));
                ArrayList<Integer> parent_temp2 = population.get(r.nextInt(population_size));
                int fitness_1 = this.evaluationSolution(parent_temp1);
                int fitness_2 = this.evaluationSolution(parent_temp2);
                ArrayList<Integer> parent = parent_temp1;
                if (fitness_1 < fitness_2) {
                    parent = parent_temp2;
                }
                parents.add(parent);
            }
           ArrayList<Integer> offspring = new ArrayList<>();
           if(r.nextFloat() < crossover_probability)
                offspring = this.performCrossover(parents.get(0), parents.get(1));
           else
               offspring = parents.get(0);

           if(r.nextFloat() < mutation_probability)
                offspring = this.performMutation(offspring);

          new_population.add((ArrayList<Integer>) offspring.clone());
        }
        return new_population;


    }

    public int evaluationSolution(ArrayList<Integer> Solution){
        int fitness = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Solution.size(); i++) {
            fitness+=(i*Solution.get(i));

        }
        return fitness;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> performCrossover(ArrayList<Integer> Parent1, ArrayList<Integer> Parent2){
        ArrayList<Integer> crossedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int crossover_point = 0;
        while (crossover_point == 0) {
            crossover_point = r.nextInt(Parent1.size());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < crossover_point; i++) {
            crossedList.add(Parent1.get(i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Parent2.size(); i++) {
            if (!crossedList.contains(Parent2.get(i))) {
                crossedList.add(Parent2.get(i));
            }
        }
        return crossedList;

    }



       public ArrayList<Integer> performMutation(ArrayList<Integer> Solution){
        ArrayList<Integer> mutatedList = new ArrayList<>();
        int mutation_point = 0;
        int insertion_point = 0;
        while (mutation_point == 0) {
            mutation_point = r.nextInt(Solution.size());
        }
        while (insertion_point == 0|| insertion_point == mutation_point) {
            insertion_point = r.nextInt(Solution.size());
        }

        mutatedList.addAll(Solution);
        int value_to_displace = Solution.get(mutation_point);
        mutatedList.remove(mutation_point);
        mutatedList.add(insertion_point, value_to_displace);


        return mutatedList;

    }



}
```

I hope this helps